# Are there any jenkins plugins for choice parameters that amend themselves after a new entry?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, parameters, jenkins-plugins, hudson

Are there any jenkins plugins for choice parameters that amend themselves after a new entry if the build succeeds?

Basically, something like this:

```
-Choice Parameter-
Name: All_Choices_So_Far
Choices:
First_Default_Choice
${New_Choice}
```

So when someone picks `${New_Choice}` and fills out the `New_Choice` field, whatever goes there then does the following, conceptually, not syntactically, as I don't know what the actual syntax would be:

```
Build Succeeded? If so then,
All_Choices_So_Far.Choices.add(${New_Choice})
All_Choices_So_Far.Choices = All_Choices_So_Far.Choices.uniq
Apply & Save Config
```

I don't actually care about the workflow being that specific, but that's roughly the functionality that I'm looking for.

Although I've yet to make a Jenkins plugin myself, if this doesn't already exist, I would be interested in how to pursue it.